# Angular2 Material2 - sidenav independent from content

Tags: css, angular, layout, angular2-material

I'm trying to use material2 sidenav component. I want it to be separate from content. Just a full-height sidebar that slides there and back - without any sidenav-layout as it creates some unwanted things in my app layout.

What I want looks really close to https://inbox.google.com/u/0/?pli=1 sidenav.
What I currently have is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What unwanted things you are talking about?

Comment: Several. Firstly, I don't want nor dimmer across my content, nor pushing the rest of my app. Basically I want something like mixed "over" with "side" mode. Also, I want to leave space for the top nav without sidenav covering it when out.

Comment: I tried putting top navigation out of the sidenav-layout and removing fullscreen directive from the layout not to cover it. This solved one problem but created the other. Non-fullscreen sidenav layout is not the solution. The thing I want is to make the sidenav full height without covering top-nav. I attached screenshots.

Comment: And also in the "side" mode it creates horizontal scrolling if content is wide enough as it pushes it to the right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate side bar and main content, Use the bootstrap column classes to achieve as below,

```
<md-sidenav-container class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-11">
    Main content goes here
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
   Manu bar
  </md-sidenav>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Note:Break tags are added to increase the height of the content.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/UUFltEZ0VowRsMpDuDvN?p=preview)**